# How to Add External CSS in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am new in Laravel...

**web.php**

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('method1.home');
});
```

**home.blade.php**

```
@extends('dashboard')
```

**dashboard.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js">
<head>
    @include('includes.head')
</head>

<body>
do something...
</body>
```

**head.blade.php**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('front_view/css/main.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('front_view/css/shop.css') }}">
<script src="{{ asset('front_view/js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js') }}"></script>
```

The path and folder name is correct.

But the CSS is not working.

Comment: what directory is `front_view` in?

Comment: front_view is a folder in public folder and in front_view all css and js are placed

Comment: Those are not "external" though, they are located on your server/domain. Have you tried looking at the source to see if the path is correct? Other than that, try `asset(..)` instead of `URL::asset(..)` like you did with your Javascript

Comment: Does the `includes.head` view contains `head.blade.php`?

Comment: I tried asset(..) instead of URL::asset(..)...but not wrking

Comment: yes includes.head view contains head.blade.php

Comment: `asset()` and `URL::asset` are the same. `asset()` is just an alias.

Check the page source from your browser to see if it's correctly included (Right click -> view page source). If yes, open the developer tools and go to the Network tab. Check that the requests for the css files return status code 200.

Comment: in viewsource:  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/admin_laravel/front_view/css/bootstrap.min.css">

Comment: path is correct

Comment: Status Code: 404 Not Found

Comment: That doesn't look like the correct path, should be `http://localhost` I think. Are you using Apache as your server or `php artisan serve`? Do you have a vhost set up?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('public/front_view/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">..when add public in path..now its work

Comment: Your server is not set up correct if you need to use `public` anywhere in your routes. `public` should be your server's `DocumentRoot`. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/installation#installing-laravel

Answer (score 0):

open or create file if not exist constants.php inside config folder and then add this line inside that file

```
define('SITE_PATH', 'http://localhost:8000/'); // write here you site url
```

and then use like this in view

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo SITE_PATH; ?>css/custom.css">
```

it will search for custom.css inside public/css folder so create css folder inside public folder and the create your custom.css or create directly inside you public folder

Comment: Thank you for reply. But no any constants.php in my config folder

Comment: It worked. When I include public in path.....<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('public/front_view/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">